# Escaping % in MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

**I found a sneaky comma in my long complicated SELECT statement**

In a python script, I have a line like

```
con.execute("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_recieved, '%%m/%%d/%%Y') from raw_table")
```

However, this makes MySQLdb unhappy, and complains:

```
File "/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", 
line 183, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I don't want any arguments. I want to pass the '%' onto MySQL (I really want'%m/%d/%Y' but tried escaping the percent: %%).

Comment: maybe you have to escape them twice: `%%%m/%%%d/%%%Y`

Comment: @furins nope, that doesn't work. then it makes it think that %m is a format character.

Comment: have you tried both with 3 and 4 `%`?

Comment: with four % it's the original error message

Comment: and what about with three `%`, what error do you get? (sorry I cannot install MySQL-python at the moment to test it by myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not providing any parameters to your query, hence `%`'s are treated literally.

Simple:

```
con.execute("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_recieved, '%m/%d/%Y') from raw_table")
```

should work.

Passing an empty parameter-tuple and escaping percents should work too:

```
con.execute("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_recieved, '%%m/%%d/%%Y') from raw_table", ())
```

It's not MySQLdb specific.

This:

```
print "a %s %d"
```

works - percent sign is interpreted literally, while this:

```
print "a %s %d" % ()
```

doesn't.